# Optimise my query

Tags: oracle-11g

```
select 
   REMITTORACCOUNTNUMBER,
   TRANTYPE,
   RRN,
   AMOUNT,
   responsecode ,
        (CASE 
     when auxrc is NULL then 'N' 
     else auxrc END) as cbsstatus,
    responsecode as switchstatus
from 
   tableA t 
   left join tableB i on t.rrn=i.TransactionSerialNumber 
where 
   traninfo like '%O' 
   and txndate>'2018-10-24' 
   and txndate<='2018-10-25';
```

It is taking more time to get a response after creating indexes.

Can you help me optimize my query for best performance?

tableA columns : REMITTORACCOUNTNUMBER,
       TRANTYPE,
       RRN,
       AMOUNT,
       responsecode ,
auxrc,traninfo
       and txndate .

tableA Indexes columns :rrn,txndate

tableB columns: TransactionSerialNumber

tableB indexes :TransactionSerialNumber

I required based on tableA which records are exists in tableB and which records are not exists in tableB.
comparison column in tableA is rrn and tableB is  TransactionSerialNumber

Comment: So what you are using? `Mysql` or `Oracle`?

Comment: we are using oracle

Comment: Specify table alias for **EACH** field in your query.

Comment: If you think slow use this [Explain](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#i3305) for see plan execution..

Comment: Unfortunately `traninfo like '%O'` can't be optimized. Only `like 'O%'` and not `like '%O%'` or `like '%O'` can be speeded up by index.

Comment: All we can offer with this little to go on is guesswork (I have an idea, but prefer not to just "guess"). You should provide basic table definitions including what indexes and keys exist on "tableA" and "tableB". It would also be helpful (as suggested already by Akina) to include the query plan the engine is currently using. The more detail you provide, the more you help us help you. Please add the extra detail by editing the question, rather than by replying to comments directly, as details in comments can easily get buried.

Comment: Please provide full table and index definitions, and the execution plan of your query.

Answer (score 1):

`INDEX(txndate)` will help some.  But that is all.

Your inequalities seem strange.  You are leaving out midnight of the first day, then spilling into the second day.  Normally one uses `>=` and `<`.